# How to show number of users in chart control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, charts

I want to show total number of users whose data is stored in a table in SQL database which is based on year in chart control in asp.net i.e. all the users who registered in a particular year, these data should be displayed for all the months in a year. Firstly I have to show data for all the years. Than the user can select a particular year from the dropdownlist and than populate the chart control for that particular year. When the user has selected a year from dropdownlist than for that particular year the data should be populated for individual months example: 40 users from Jan, 85 from March, etc.

```
                int month = 1;

                for (int i = month; i <= 12; i++)
                {
                    var usercount = (from u in context.Profiles
                                     where u.CreatedOn.Month == month
                                     select u).Count();
                }
```

I am using entity framework for writing the database related codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get it : juste use a where and a group by ?

```
var groups = context.Profiles
                     .Where(u => u.CreatedOn.Year == <someYear>)
                     .GroupBy(u => u.CreatedOn.Month)
                              .Select(g => new {
                                      month = g.Key,
                                      nbUsers = g.Count()
                                      });
```